# $\partial_S(U) \subset (\partial_S(S') \cup \partial_{S'}(U))$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Show that $\partial_S(U) \subset (\partial_S(S') \cup
>  \partial_{S'}(U))$    where $S'$ is subspace of the metric space
> $(S,d)$. $U$ is nonempty subset of $S'$.

To approach this problem, should I divide it into several cases (I think there are four cases)?

Or Should I start from
$\partial_S(U) = cl_S(U) \cap cl_S(S\backslash U)$?

I'm kinda stuck on both ways. For the second one, I have:
$\partial_S(U) = cl_S(U) \cap cl_S(S\backslash U)$
$\subset cl_S(S') \cap cl_S(S\backslash U)$.

Or is there a counterexample to the statement??